# Understanding styles

Tags: android, button, themes

I'm trying to set a custom colour for my buttons in Android application but value set for accentColor is always used as button background colour. I am trying to set a global colour for all buttons without having to specify styles or theme for each button individually.

Can you explain please how styling works in Android? I understand the basics, but overriding existing themes is never working for me :(

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button" >
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with MaterialComponents. When using AppCompact the above works just fine.

Comment: Oh, I just saw this comment. So, as I mentioned, each theme may define the way they set the color, so try going to the source code of how the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` is defining the style for the buttons and override those attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. The main point to notice here is that I am using **Theme.MaterialComponents** and not AppCompact.

I have defined a new style and I set it to buttonStyle, which refers to style for AppCompact button. In order to set a style for the material button, I had to use "materialButtonStyle" instead of "buttonStyle".

All relevant properties that can be overridden for MaterialComponents can be found in material design documentation: https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

So the final code looks like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Test</item>
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
        <!--<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">#D400EB</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Test" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">#A305B1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Short answer: Try going to the source code of how the
>   `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` is defining the style for
>   the buttons and override those attributes.

Android styling works by merging all the defined attributes in a theme. For example, you have an `AppTheme` that includes theming for every built-in view. If you create a new theme for your button and your define just a couple of attributes, what android studio does is to merge all the attributes defined in the `AppTheme` with your new attributes. So if you want to override the buttons, you need to go deep and find out what are exactly the attributes defined in the general `AppTheme` you set in your application, they may not be the same.

For example, this is how I changed the color of all the buttons in my app since they were using a global attribute for it:
In the general styles.xml file, I put:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?myCustomColor</item>
    ...
</style>
```

But if I wanted to change the `backgroundTint` attribute of my buttons, I had to do this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?myCustomColor</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppButtonStyle</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Also, check out [this cool Medium post](https://medium.com/@joannekao/android-working-with-themes-and-styles-18cde717f4d) for another developer experience in this topic.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I actually managed to find the solution to my problem, which is essentially what you explained but in relation to MaterialComponents

Comment: Nice! Glad you found your solution.